# Getting Collection of particular Type with Hybris ModelService

Tags: interceptor, sap-commerce-cloud

Hiy!

I want all objects(rows in Test Type) with ModelService

So I could iterate through collection and update a Single row (object)'s attribute with new value

I see `getModelService.create(TestModel.class)` and `getModelService.save()`
but will they not create a new object/row rather than update a existing object?right 
I don't want to create a new one rather selecting one of the existing matching my criteria and update one attribute of that

can somebody help with `List<TestModel> testModels = getModelService.get(TestModel.class)` will that return me all rows (collection) of Test Type/Table?

unfortunately I can't test it so need help

Actually I am in validateInterceptor ... and on the basis of this intercepted model changed attribute value I have to update another model attribute value...

thanks

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] for information on how to best revise your posting so it is clear and understandable. If possible also create an [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

`ModelService.create(new TestModel.class)` will create a single instance of the specified type and attach it to the modelservice's context.
But it will only be saved to the persistence store when you call `modelService.save(newInstance)`

`ModelService.get()` returns a model object but expects a Jalo object as input, (Jalo being the legacy persistence layer of hybris) so that won't work for you.

To retrieve objects you can either write your own queries using the `FlexibleSearchService` or you can have a look at the `DefaultGenericDao` which has a bunch of simple `find()` type of methods.

Typically you would inject the dao like e.g.:

```
private GenericDao<TestModel> dao;

[...]

public void myMethod()
{
    List<TestModel> allTestModels = dao.find();

    [...]
}
```

There are a lot more methods with which you can create `WHERE` type of statements to restrict your result.

Regarding `ValidateInterceptor`:
Have a look at the wiki page for the lifecycle of interceptors:
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Interceptors

It's not a good idea to modify 'all' objects of a type while being an interceptor of that type.
So if you're in an interceptor declared for the `Test` item type, then don't try to modify the items there.
If you happen to be in a different interceptor and want to modify items of a different type:
E.g. you have `Type1` which has a list of `Type2` objects in it and in the interceptor for `Type1` you want to modify all `Type2` objects.
For those scenarios you would have to add the instances of `Type2` that you modify to the interceptor context so that those changes will be persisted.
That would be something like:

```
void onValidate(Test1 model, InterceptorContext ctx) throws InterceptorException
{
   ...
   List<Type2> type2s = dao.find();
   for (Type2 type2 : type2s)
   {
      // do something with it
      // then make sure to persist that change
      ctx.registerElementFor(type2, PersistenceOperation.SAVE);
      [...]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - i think it's not a good idea, to create/update models in any interceptor, especially in 'validation' one.

Regarding your question:

1. ModelService in most of the cases works with single model, and
   designed for create/update/delete operations.
2. To retreive all models of certain type, you have to use FlexibleSearchService
3. Then to update each retrieved TestType model, you can use ModelService's `save` method.

A query to retreive all `TestType` models will look like:
`SELECT PK FROM {TestType}`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the Flexible Search Service search by example method, and the model service to save them all. Here is an example using Groovy script, with all products :

```
import java.util.List
import de.hybris.platform.core.model.product.ProductModel
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchService
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ModelService

FlexibleSearchService fsq = spring.getBean("flexibleSearchService")
ModelService ms = spring.getBean("modelService")

ProductModel prd = ms.create(ProductModel.class)
List<ProductModel> products = fsq.getModelsByExample(prd)

//Do Whatever you want with the objects in the List

ms.saveAll(products)
```